# From Docker container CPU stat to Kubernetes pod CPU requirement

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gcp, migration

Say I have 3 containers in a 8 CPU host in GCP and they have had the following CPU% mean usage for the last week:

| CONTAINER | CPU % |
| --- | --- |
| app1 | 500% |
| app2 | 100% |
| app3 | 50% |

Now I want to migrate to Kubernetes. Based on the data above I want to get a CPU soft limit (requirement) for each app's pod in Kubernetes in millicpu.

How would you go around it?

**Option 1:** millicpu_requirement = cpu_perc * 10

**Option 2:** millicpu_requirement = cpu_perc * 100 * 8

**Option 3:** millicpu_requirement = ?